# C - Writing integers to binary file using only 3 bytes

Tags: c, file, io, binary

I have a programm in C that writes a frequency table to a binary file.
The frequency table is an array filled with structs that contains an int and a char.

So I have to write an unsigned int counter and an unsigned char character to the file (multiple times).

I know that an integer normally uses 4 bytes however I know that the int counter can never be bigger than 2^24-1.

So I could use 4 bytes to write the counter and the character to the file => 3 bytes for counter and 1 byte for the character. This would also be easy to read.

Is there an easy way to do this in C without using special libraries?

Comment: This can be done easily using a `char[4]` and `fread`/`fwrite`.  If that's not enough of a hint, please be more specific about what you don't know how to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a very easy way of doing it in C. You can combine a `char`, which is one byte on all platforms, with an int of up to 24 bits in size by shifting the `char` by 24 bits to the left:

```
uint32_t toWrite = (myChar << 24) | myCount;
```

When you read the data back, perform the opposite operation:

```
uint32_t fromFile;
uint32_t myCount = fromFile & 0xFFFFFF;
char myChar = (fromFile >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: Now you have an endianness problem.  Also, shifting into the sign bit is UB.

Comment: @zwol integers do not have any endianness.

Comment: @WeatherVane The bytes written to a file when you do `fwrite(&toWrite, sizeof(int), 1, fp)` have an endianness, and you don't know which one.

Comment: @zwol Writing a multi-byte value to a file carries the endianness with it. As long as you read the data on a platform with the same endianness, you don't have to do anything. Otherwise, you'd need to apply `hton` / `ntoh` functions.

Comment: @zwol there is nothing differnt from writing a 32-bit `int` to a file, though I agree that `char` should be `unsigned`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I guess what I'm saying is "I think it's bad advice to suggest code that writes binary quantities to a file without an explicit conversion to a fixed endianness".

Comment: @zwol To me, this depends on the purpose of writing the file in the first place. If this is a quick job for short-term storage and retrieval, dumping the memory format is acceptable. If this is something that you intend to keep for a long period of time (say, a couple of years), or you want your cross-platform compatibility, using a predictable order is a good choice.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight purpose is an easy compression algorithm, could you also explain the 0xFFFFFF and  0xFF?

Comment: @fangio `0xFFFFFF` is a bit mask with its last 24 bits set. It serves to keep the final 24 bits, and drop the other ones. `0xFF` keeps the final 8 bits, i.e. the `char` value shifted into position.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Given how often code that's meant for "I'll just use it this one time" sticks around, I'd say handle endianness properly no matter what.  It takes all of one more line of code to call `hton`/`ntoh`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm thinking more about the hypothetical future readers, who _could_ be designing archival file formats, whether or not the OP is.

Comment: @zwol The endian-ness is a _good idea_ except OP has only provided scant details.  The point is that code could have a packing invariant requirement necessitating functionality - inefficiently expressed as `fputc(data_char, ...);  /* data first then count */ uint24_t count24 = count; count24 = hton24(count24);  fwrite(&count24, 3,1,...)`.  IAC, your concern about long-term file data stability is very valid.